# Passing state to another component with history.push() method

Tags: reactjs

In my project I am trying to log all answers when user clicks on submit button. There are two components and each has different questions. After finishing section 1 question when user clicks on NEXT button then state should be passed to another component in order to log answers for that I am using history.push(/path, [state]) to pass data but it's not working. Can anyone tell me how to solve the issue ? When I click on submit button then only question 4 and 5 answers get logged as shown in output.

code ::

Section.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import Answers from "../Answers/Answers";

class Section extends Component {
    state = {
        que1: "",
        que2: "",
        que3: ""
    };

    handleClick = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que1: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que1);
            }
        );
    };

    handleClick2 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que2);
            }
        );
    };

    handleClick3 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que3: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que3);
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        let styles = {
            width: '50%',
            margin: '0 auto',
            marginBottom: '15px'
        }
        console.log(this.state);
        const { history } = this.props;
        const { que1, que2, que3 } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <p>1. I was stressed with my nerves on edge.</p>
                <Button.Group selected={this.state.que1} widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick} style={styles}>
                    <Answers style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                </Button.Group>
                {` `}
                <p>2. I lost hope and wanted to give up when something went wrong.</p>
                <Button.Group selected={this.state.que2} widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick2} style={styles}>
                    <Answers style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                </Button.Group>
                {` `}
                <p>3. I feel very satisfied with the way I look and act</p>
                <Button.Group selected={this.state.que3} widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick3} style={styles}>
                    <Answers style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                </Button.Group>
                <p />
                {` `}
                <Button
                    disabled={!que1 || !que2 || !que3}
                    onClick={() => history.push("/section2", [this.state])}
                >
                    NEXT
        </Button>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Section);
```

[image]

Section2.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Answers from "../Answers/Answers";
import CommonButton from "../CommonButton/CommonButton";
import SectionIndicator from "../../components/SectionIndicator/SectionIndicator";

export class Section2 extends Component {

    state = {
        que4: "",
        que5: ""
    };

    handleClick4 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que4: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que4);
            }
        );
    };

    handleClick5 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que5: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que5);
            }
        );
    };

    handleClickForSubmit = () => {
        console.log(this.state)
    }


    render() {
        let styles = {
            width: '50%',
            margin: '0 auto',
            marginBottom: '15px'
        }

        let style2 = {
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        }
        console.log(this.state);
        const { history } = this.props;
        return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <SectionIndicator value={"2"} total={"2"} progress={"ratio"} />
                <p>4. How many times do you eat in a day when you are stressed.</p>
                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick4} style={styles}>
                    <Answers />
                </Button.Group>

                <span />
                <p>5. Do you prefer to work when you are stressed.</p>

                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick5} style={styles}>
                    <Answers />
                </Button.Group>
                <Link to="/assess" style={style2}>
                    {" "}
                    <CommonButton text={"PREVIOUS"} onClick={() => history.goBack()} />
                    <CommonButton text={"SUBMIT"} onClick={this.handleClickForSubmit} />
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Section2;
```

[image]

output ::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to persist your data across a page change:

1. Use Redux a global state management system.
2. Use a form component which has all the values it needs in Component state. The key is to ensure that this component doesn't get unmounted (destroyed) otherwise all the state will be gone.
3. Use LocalStorage or SessionStorage to save/retrieve the values.
4. Save the values to the window object (not a very elegant solution)

Comment: Is there any other way apart from redux ?

Comment: yes - see 2,3 and 4!! Seriously though, I think you probably just need to ensure that Section and Section2 components are not destroyed (and therefore lose your state)

Comment: Form component should be used to feed input related value. Should I really use it in my case ?